# How to create .razor files

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I've created a Blazor project using .net core 3.0 preview5 and VS2019 Enterprise.  I want to create .razor files, but all of my options have .cshtml extensions.

When I'm creating my project, I'm using asp.net core 3.0 and Blazor server hosted options

Comment: Did you try to create cshtml and change it yo razor ?

Comment: I created a razor view page and razor page and changed the extension to .razor and got a bunch of errors.

Comment: What is error message? Do you update vs 2019 to the latest version? Do you follow steps like Right-click Pages folder -> Add new item-> Razor View-> change extension to .razor?

Comment: The error I received was that it didn't recognize my annotations.  I could have added a reference, but since I didn't have to with the default index.razor page, I didn't think converting a razor view was an option.

Answer (score 4):

In VS 2019 16.3.0, adding "Razor Component" is what worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What works is:

Add, Add Class

and then change `.cs` to `.razor` **before** clicking [Add]

And immediately delete all the C# stuff of course.

Or you can copy/paste/rename any existing blazor component, like `index.razor`.

Comment: That worked.  I'm not sure why there isn't an option to create .razor pages directly from add new item, though.

Comment: Well, that requires changes to VS. I guess that's low on the prio list and too much bother for now. Give it one or two more Preview releases.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've got the blazor extension installed. 
[image]

This should then allow you to click on the Pages Directory and at the top there's an Add Razor Page option.
[image]

But I've got to admit, I tend to find it quicker to just select an existing page in the solution explorer and Ctrl-C Ctrl-V and rename it!

Note: At time of writing this is using the preview branch of Visual Studio 2019 and frameworks.

Comment: "Razor Page" doesn't work for me...  A "Razor View" does.

Comment: I didn't see your response until after I saw the other one.  I do see the Add Razor Page option, but when I click that option, I get the error: "There are no scaffolders supported for this item."  I did make a copy of my index.razor page and renamed it before I posted, but I didn't know if that was an acceptable option.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Pages-> Add->New Item...-> Razor Component

[image]